# How to loop through tuples in a Bag, Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am new to pig scripting.

I have an input,  `(A,B,{(XYZ,123,CDE)})`

I am looking to loop through the bag inside and print the following records.

```
(A,B,XYZ)  
(A,B,123)
(A,B,CDE)
```

Can someone please help me out!

Answer (score 1):

Lets say X is your relation and it has `(A,B,{(XYZ,123,CDE)})`.ToBag converts the expression into bags and FLATTEN unnests the tuples,bag.

```
Y = FOREACH X GENERATE $0,$1,ToBag(FLATTEN($2));
```

Comment: Hi, using FLATTEN will print records in the following way: (A,B,XYZ,123,CDE)

Comment: I would like to insert a new record for every tuple in the bag.

Comment: @miniscule001 Try ToBag(FLATTEN($2))

Answer (score 1):

Solved!!

Let us load below file (Tab separated)

A   B   {(XYZ,123,CDE)}

```
input_plus_bag = load '' USING PigStorage() AS (entry1:chararray, entry2:chararray, bag1:bag{(te1:chararray, te2:int, te3:chararray)});

intermed_output = foreach input_plus_bag generate entry1, entry2, FLATTEN(bag1);

Dump intermed_output;
```

This will give

(A,B,XYZ,123,CDE)

```
DESCRIBE intermed_output;

intermed_output: {entry1: chararray,entry2: chararray,bag1::te1: chararray,bag1::te2: int,bag1::te3: chararray}
```

Now perform TOBAG operation

```
intermed2_output = foreach intermed_output generate entry1, entry2, TOBAG(bag1::te1,bag1::te2,bag1::te3);

 DUMP intermed2_output;
```

This will result in below output:-

(A,B,{(XYZ),(123),(CDE)})

Now final step is FLATTEN the bag

```
final_output = foreach intermed2_output generate entry1, entry2, FLATTEN($2);
```

And we have our desired output:-

```
(A,B,XYZ)
(A,B,123)
(A,B,CDE)
```